# Последовательный вызов нескольких методов по нажатию одной кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопка, по нажатию на нее должно вызваться три метода, каждый из них обновляет одно поле документа базы данных .

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    income();
    expenses();
    balance();                                  
}
```

Нужно чтобы эти три метода вызывались последовательно, т.к. метод balance обновляет БД на основе данных полученных после обновления  методами income и expenses. Но вместо этого почему-то после нажатия кнопки срабатывает только один из трех методов. То есть после первого нажатия обновляется одно из трех полей, после второго -следующее и т.д.

Comment: Код, который вы привели, правильный. Ищите ошибку в другом месте. Например, один из методов может завершаться с исключением.

Comment: что такое "документ базы данных"?

Comment: Для получения ответа дополните свой вопрос кодом методов `income`, `expenses` и `balance`. Как вам уже написали, возможно падает исключение. Либо просто оберните тела методов в блоки `try...catch` отловите ошибку и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Спасибо,решил проблему вызовом функции в теле предыдущей функции ,как-то сразу об этом и не сообразил.